# Forcing an ARP request

Tags: routing, ipv4, arp, packet-analysis

I'm writing a program that detects ARP poisoning. What I want to do is somehow clear my routers ARP cache, so that it can force send an ARP request, so then I can check the source address of the packet and see if it's from somewhere other than my default gateway.

I've just got a question:

Instead of somehow clearing my routers arp cache, could I just request a new DHCP IP address. Would this force the router to send an ARP request for the new IP address when it's receiving packets from the internet?

Comment: Is your goal for the Router to send *any* ARP Request?  Or to send an ARP Request targeting a *specific IP Address*?

Comment: My goal is for the router to send an ARP request using my new IP address that I've assigned by DHCP. This way I can detect the ARP packet and check the source address as that being from the router.

So after I've changed the IP address on my host machine, I plan to use ping requests to get packets. My understanding is since there is a new IP address that the router arp-cache doesn't know about, it will send an ARP request when it receives packets from the outside.

Comment: What model of router, and what is the configuration?  I will never understand why people ask these kind of questions without the most basic information

Comment: Also our [NetEng Q Checklist](http://meta.networkengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/292/network-engineering-question-checklist) is very helpful.

Answer (score 1):

*The OP's approach seems backwards to me or I am really misreading the question.  I would never taken an approach that attempts to force the router to clear its cache to aid some external monitoring.*

If you're trying to confirm the IP-MAC of the router being spoofed, who cares about the ARP for your client?  If you already know the router IP-MAC to confirm from the client, **the client [program] should be the one sending out an ARP for its gateway (IP) and confirm the unicast response containing the gateway's MAC address.**

Assuming you don't know the gateway's IP-MAC initially, you'll have to take the first one seen on faith, then monitor all other ARP requests from that gateway to detect a change that would trigger some sort of alert by your program.  On Cisco devices, the default ARP aging is 240 min, so you'll see at least one ARP per client every 4 hours to generate these requests organically.

To really spot ARP poisoning, **Gratuitious ARPs** would most like come into play.  These should be monitored as well.  Your program could become a change detector for ARPs in that you persist the IP-MAC mappings seen for the life of your program and you don't clear that mapping every 4 hours the way ARP aging does and blindly accepts the next ARP response as valid.

Answer (score 0):

If your PC changes IP address, then yes, the router will need to ARP for it when next it needs to send you traffic.

Simply renewing your IP Address via DHCP is unlikely to change anything, as most DHCP servers will simply re-allocate you the same address you have already leased which your router will already have stored in ARP cache.

Comment: is there any way to get the DHCP server to assign me a different IP address?

Alternatively, if there's a DHCP server on my router, could I just manually change my ipv4 address to something else then (i.e. static)? Would the DHCP server still being on, stop this from happening at all?

Comment: Just manually assign yourself an unused IP address with correct gateway and you'll be fine.